# Laravel Route get controller's construct without method

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get('customer/{id}', 'Customer@method'); <-- want to call construct not method

class Customer extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        echo 123456;
    }
```

I'm new in laravel

I try to call __construct from my controller without method, but I got error, is anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What error you get??

Comment: That's a weird use case. What's the real world use case?

Comment: Constructor called automatically... and then your method...

Comment: if i did get(...'Customer'); without @method, i got Invalid route action

Comment: I don't want to call any method, i only want construct

Comment: do you know how constructor called? study first

Comment: i know, because some of controller only got 1 method, so no reason i create method and call again, just do it in construct

Comment: Have you try my answer below??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do like this

1. Define route

> Route::resource('customer/{id}', 'Customer');

2. In your Customer Controller

> ```
> use Route;
> public function __construct()
> {
>   $id = Route::current()->getParameter('id');
>   dd($id);
> }
> ```

Comment: possible to make it more clean? i wish my controller only have controller log, something like Route::get(....,'Customer') ;